# How to parse input from AWS event rule in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, jobs

If I use the input in an events rule.. how am I supposed parse it in the lambda?

Now I have:

```
  MyJobScheduledRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: Scheduled Rule
      ScheduleExpression: !Sub "rate(${IntervalMinutes} minutes)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Id: "MyJobLambda"
          Arn: !GetAtt MyJobLambda.Arn
          Input: "\"{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}\"
```

With the following lambda:

```
public class MyJobLambda implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, Void>  {
  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJobLambda.class);

  @Override
  public Void handleRequest(Map<String, String> event, Context context) {

    LOGGER.debug("MyJob got value {} from input", event.get("key"));

    return null;
  }

}
```

But I get the following runtime exception:

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('
{
    "key": "value"
}
```

I have also tried using a POJO as input to the lambda. Any ideas?

Comment: You can just print out `event` object and check its structure in CloudWatch Logs

Comment: event.readValueAsTree().toString() <- try this

Comment: And in your case what type would event be?

Answer (score 1):

Use a ScheduledEvent object, and parse the detail field of the event

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.ScheduledEvent;
public class MyJobLambda implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, Void>  {
  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJobLambda.class);

  @Override
  public Void handleRequest(ScheduledEvent event, Context context) {

    LOGGER.debug("MyJob got value {} from input", mapScheduledEventDetail(event.getDetail());

    return null;
  }

 private String mapScheduledEventDetail(Map<String,Object> detailObject) {
       return ParserUtil.parseObjectToJson(detailObject.get("clientId"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Got this compile error `Class ... must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'handleRequest(I, Context)' in 'RequestHandler'`. How do you get it to compile?